# How to extract file name after grepping a string in unix

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I am using the code below to `grep` some string:

```
grep 'string' *.log | grep -v 'string1'
```

I am getting output in particular file. My requirement is to extract that file name to a variable. How I can do that effectively?

Comment: Not sure what you need exactly, but have you tried this?
`testfilename = "someFilename.txt"; echo "${testfilename%.*}`
This will return string `someFilename` (without extension).

Comment: If there is only one file in the glob, grep won't print a filename.  Typical techniques to ensure that a filename is printed are `grep -H` and `grep pattern file /dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can capture the output of any command into a shell variable via *command substitution* like this:

```
variable=$(command arg1 arg2)
```

This is appropriate for your particular case if you are sure that there will be *only one* file name produced by the `grep` pipeline.  In that case, you capture its name into shell variable `fname` via:

```
fname=$(grep -lZ string *.log | xargs -0 grep -lv string1)
```

This is safe for difficult file names because, via the `-Z` and `-0` options, we use NUL-separated lists.  The `-l` option to `grep` is useful here because it suppresses the normal `grep` output and just prints the file names.

If there might be multiple file matches, then, if you can use an advanced shell like `bash`, try:

```
grep -lZ string *.log | xargs -0 grep -lvZ string1 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' fname
do
    # Process file "$fname"
done
```

This is also safe for difficult file names because, throughout the pipeline, it uses NUL-separated lists.

For a POSIX shell, `read` works with newline-separated input.  To make the above safe for difficult file names, the `-d` option is used which is supported by `bash`, `zsh`, and other advanced shells.

Comment: Maybe you should also tell which shell supports that `read` feature.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald Good point.  I added mention that POSIX doesn't support `read -d` but that `bash` and `zsh` do (there may be other shells as well but I am not familiar with them).

Answer (score 0):

use command

basename "filePath" "fileExtension"

ex: basename /home/john/xyz.txt .txt

output: xyz